# MAF per RPM dummy data

Tags: maf

I am just studying mechanics and I wanted to test some of the formulas on some "real cases".
More specifically I wanted to test volumetric flow rate and volumetric efficiency.
I was wondering if anyone has some realistic MAF data by engine speed that I can test and play with. I tried to search online but I was not successful.
Thank you in advance for any help